# Can we bypass or opt out of the automation that moves answers to comments?

Tags: bug

This question needed an answer, not a comment.

[cronjobs do not run](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402132/cronjobs-do-not-run)

This is a horrible change since [answers belong in the answer section](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/questions/930?r=SearchResults&s=10%7C26.4255). Comments are not for answers, only for clarifications on the question. [For the moderation team](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/questions/1017)

I’ve added some faff + garbage characters to the answer to bypass this. Not sure if I’ll leave it up or edit it out later.

Please reconsider this “feature” here as I am seen: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99096/165931

Comment: Can I get some background on this? I thought “Comments are not for answers, only for clarifications on the question.” was the official policy everywhere. I know it’s not always followed, and I’m as guilty of that as anyone, but I certainly didn’t expect to see a feature that works *against* the principle...

Comment: I have had two answers I post get immediately converted into comments @Wowfunhappy so that’s the background. I know when I make a short answer and I was pretty disappointed the “code” decided to over rule me, tbh.

Comment: Okay, I did some Googling, seems to is nine years old! O_O https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment/

Comment: I edited the linked answer to not have the extra text. I figured that either (A) the feature wouldn't be triggered if the text was edited by someone else, or (B) I would discover a major exploit via which users could effectively delete other people's answers. 